# Convert binary to decimal - understaing the logic

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, binary

I needed to convert binary to decimal and I found this code here, its working perfect:

```
binary_Op1 = raw_input('enter a number: ')
decimal = 0
for digit in binary_Op1:
    decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)
print decimal
```

The thing is, I'm having some difficult understanding the logic behind it...
Why do we multiply the decimal variable by 2? Why is the decimal variable set to = 0?
Why do we the digit each time? and so on(:

Thank you.

Comment: if the input were decimal (i.e. in base 10), the multiplication would be by 10. does that help? ...and all that could be done a lot more elegant!

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain that by taking 10101 as an example input.

```
1 should be multiplied by 2^4
0 should be multiplied by 2^3
1 should be multiplied by 2^2
0 should be multiplied by 2^1
1 should be multiplied by 2^0
and Add everything.
```

Program starts by multiplying 2 each time it encounters a number. So basically first 1 will be multiplied 4 times and first 0 3 times and same till the last 1.

Something like this.

```
1 *2 *2 *2 *2
0 *2 *2 *2
1 *2 *2
0 *2 
1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's less a programming question than a maths question.

Try an example: `1100101`

```
decimal = 0

# First digit: 1
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 0*2 + 1 = 1

# Second digit: 1
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 1*2 + 1 = 3

# Third digit: 0
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 3*2 + 0 = 6

# Fourth digit: 0
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 6*2 + 0 = 12

# Fifth digit: 1
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 12*2 + 1 = 25

# Sixth digit: 0
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 25*2 + 0 = 50

# Seventh digit: 1
decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit)  # decimal = 50*2 + 1 = 101
```

Voilá! Answer is 101.

It works by doubling every `1`as many times as digits are following.
This way higher valued digits get actually a higher value (1,2,4,8,16,32 ...)

This works for the decimal system as well:

Try: `1337`

```
decimal = 0

# First digit: 1
decimal = decimal*10 + digit  # decimal = 0*10 + 1 = 1

# Second digit: 3
decimal = decimal*10 + digit  # decimal = 1*10 + 3 = 13

# Third digit: 3
decimal = decimal*10 + digit  # decimal = 13*10 + 3 = 133

# Fourth digit: 7
decimal = decimal*10 + digit  # decimal = 133*10 + 7 = 1337
```

Voilá! Answer is 1337.

Addendum:
The [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) uses the same principle to evaluate polynomials at some given point.

Comment: Addendum: The [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) uses the same principle to evaluate polynomials at some given point.